# WPF How to disable rotation of some elements while screen rotate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, screen-orientation, win-universal-app

I am currently creating Win 8.1 universal app. It should have both landscape and portrait view. But only difference between these two states is, that some elements just "turn" to proper direction, while main grid will not rotate.

[I don't have enough reputation so here is link to picture of my notion](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9p346y1fp5ra6ty/example.gif?dl=0)

Is there any way to disable state change rotation only within some elements or do I have to detect the screen orientation and just rotate the desired elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather a simple issue and you should implement your second method:

- Identify the elements that should not rotate
- Rotate them the opposite direction to the screen